# Two dimentional array of objects from json file

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I'm trying to create an object that has a two dimensional array of objects.
I'm using gson for that, here the code:

```
Gson g=new Gson();
JsonObject o =(JsonObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\simulation[2].json"));
SimulationInput si=g.fromJson(o, SimulationInput.class);
```

Here is the json file:

```
{
"threads": 4,

"tools": [
    {
        "tool": "gs-driver",
        "qty": 35
    },
    {
        "tool": "np-hammer",
        "qty": 17
    },
    {
        "tool": "rs-pliers",
        "qty": 23
    }
],
"plans": [
    {
        "product": "yphone30",
        "tools": ["gs-driver", "rs-pliers"],
        "parts": ["5'-screen", "round-button"]
    },
    {
        "product": "yphone30-pro",
        "tools": ["gs-driver", "np-hammer"],
        "parts": ["6'-screen", "round-button", "camera"]
    },
    {
        "product": "yphone30-pro-plus",
        "tools": ["gs-driver", "np-hammer", "rs-pliers"],
        "parts": ["10'-screen", "round-button", "camera", "headphone-jack"]
    },
    {
        "product": "5'-screen",
        "tools": ["np-hammer"],
        "parts": ["glass", "touch-controller"]
    },
    {
        "product": "6'-screen",
        "tools": ["np-hammer", "rs-pliers"],
        "parts": ["glass", "touch-controller"]
    },
    {
        "product": "10'-screen",
        "tools": [],
        "parts": ["5'-screen", "5'-screen"]
    },
    {
        "product": "round-button",
        "tools": ["gs-driver"],
        "parts": ["round-stuff", "electrical-things"]
    },
    {
        "product": "camera",
        "tools": ["gs-driver", "rs-pliers"],
        "parts": ["glass", "round-stuff"]
    },
    {
        "product": "headphone-jack",
        "tools": ["rs-pliers"],
        "parts": ["round-stuff"]
    },
    {
        "product": "touch-controller",
        "tools": ["rs-pliers", "np-hammer"],
        "parts": ["electrical-things"]
    },
    {
        "product": "glass",
        "tools": ["np-hammer"],
        "parts": []
    },
    {
        "product": "round-stuff",
        "tools": ["rs-pliers"],
        "parts": []
    },
    {
        "product": "electrical-things",
        "tools": ["gs-driver"],
        "parts": []
    }
],
"waves": [
    [
        {
            "product": "yphone30",
            "qty": 2,
            "startId": 50123450
        },
        {
            "product": "yphone30-pro",
            "qty": 2,
            "startId": 50234560
        },
        {
            "product": "yphone30-pro-plus",
            "qty": 3,
            "startId": 502345601
        }

    ],
    [
        {
            "product": "yphone30",
            "qty": 2,
            "startId": 501623450
        },
        {
            "product": "yphone30-pro",
            "qty": 3,
            "startId": 560234560
        },
        {
            "product": "yphone30-pro-plus",
            "qty": 2,
            "startId": 5602345601
        }
    ]
]
}
```

These are the fields of `SimulationInput`:

```
public class SimulationInput {
    private int threads;
    private ToolsQuantity[] tools;
    private ManufactoringPlan[] plans;
    private ProductDetails[][] products;
}
```

How do I instantiate each row in the 2 dimentional array from the json file?

Comment: That's a constructor?

Comment: In your json file there is a property called waves......is that the name of the products field ??

Comment: sorry thats not the constructor, thats the fields of the simulatorInput class

Comment: prashant you have solved my silly problem, thanks